# AMQP protocol on TLS/SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, amqp, azure-eventhub

How can I use AMQP protocol over TLS when communicating with Azure Event Hubs. I am using AmqpTransportSettings class with property UseSslStreamSecurity set  to true. I did not get any exception, but how do I know if my messages are transported via SSL. **Is there any tool to intercept AMQP message communication (like Fiddler or Wireshark)?** Also, do we not need certificates for SSL like in HTTPS? Please suggest if I am missing any thing.

I used the following code snippet, but I cannot be sure of AMQP is using SSL:

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "eventhub-ns", ""), new MessagingFactorySettings
        {
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(token),
            TransportType = TransportType.Amqp,
            AmqpTransportSettings = new AmqpTransportSettings() { UseSslStreamSecurity = true }
        });

var evetHubClient = factory.CreateEventHubClient(String.Format("{0}/publishers/{1}", eventHubName, publisherId))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dissector for AMQP 1.0 has been available in Wireshark since version 1.11.

Regards,
Dave.